# How to add new file to dataframe

Tags: pandas, csv, intervals, auto-update

I have a folder where CSV files are stored, AT certain interval a new CSV file(SAME FORMAT) is added to the folder.

I need to detect the new file and add the contents to data frame.

My current code reads all CSV files at once and stores in dataframe , But Dataframe should get  updated with the contents of new CSV when a new file(CSV) is added to the folder.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\XXXX\CSVFILES")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a path into your folder where new `csv` are downloaded:

```
path_csv = r"C:\........\csv_folder"
```

I assume that your dataframe (the one you want to append to) is created and that you load it into your script (you have probably updated it before, saved to some csv in another folder). Let's assume you do this:

```
path_saved_df = r"C:/..../saved_csv"   #The path to which you've saved the previously read csv:s
filename = "my_old_files.csv"
df_old = pd.read_csv(path + '/' +filename, sep="<your separator>")  #e.g. sep =";"
```

Then, to only read the latest addition of a `csv` to the folder in `path` you simply do the following:

```
list_of_csv = glob.glob(path_csv + "\\\\*.csv")
latest_csv = max(list_of_csv , key=os.path.getctime)   #max ensures you only read the latest file

with open(latest_csv) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file , delimiter=';')
    
new_file = pd.read_csv(latest_csv, sep="<your separator>", encoding ="iso-8859-1") #change encoding if you need to
```

Your new dataframe is then

```
New_df = pd.concat([df_old,new_file])
```